# All possible combinations of value-pairs (2-item tuples) in a sequence - PYTHON 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples, counter, list-comprehension

I'm having a math brain fart moment, and google has failed to answer my quandary.

Given a sequence or list of 2 item tuples (from a Counter object), how do I quickly and elegantly get python to spit out a linear sequence or array of all the possible combinations of those tuples? My goal is trying to find the combinations of results from a Counter object.....

For example clarity, if I have this sequence:

```
[(500, 2), (250, 1)]
```

Doing this example out manually by hand, it should yield these results:

```
250, 500, 750, 1000, 1250.
```

Basically, I THINK it's a*b for the range of b and then add the resulting lists together...
I've tried this (where c=Counter object):

```
res = [[k*(j+1) for j in range(c[k])] for k in c]
```

And it will give me back:

```
res = [[250], [500, 1000]]
```

So far so good, it's going through each tuple and multiplying x * y for each y... But the resulting list isn't full of all the combinations yet, the first list [250] needs to be added to each element of the second list. This would be the case for any number of results I believe.

Now I think I need to take each list in this result list and add it to the other elements in the other lists in turn. Am I going about this wrong?  I swear there should be a simpler way. I feel there should be a way to do this in a one line list comp.

Is the solution recursive? Is there a magic import or builtin method I don't know about? My head hurts......

Comment: If `750` is in the solution set, why isn't `1500`? Can you clarify the resulting set should be `[250*1, (500*1 OR 250*2),(500*1 + 250*1),(500*2 OR 250*2 + 500*1),(500*2 + 250*1)]`

Comment: I have no idea how you got those results from the input sequence.  Can you explain that a little better?

Comment: well it's a Counter object, so for each tuple in the counter, I read it in english as: x="this item", y="exists this many times"  

so, I want to find all combos of the counts of these items. 1500 should not be in the solution set because there is no way to use the "amount of items seen" to total that amount. the highest you can get is 1250 -> 500 + 500 + 250. or, in long form, both  counts of the 500 tuple count, and the single use of the 250 tuple count.   Hope that clears it up.

Comment: To fully explain, I'll go out by hand for all solutions:

    `(250 * 1) = 250
    (500 * 1) = 500
    (500 * 1) + (250 * 1) = 750
    (500 * 1) + (500 * 1) = 1000
    (500 * 1 + (500 * 1) + (250 * 1) = 1250`

there should be no other solutions.

Comment: @ACVentures so you can use item A from tuple (A,B) up to B times in a sum?

Comment: @C.B. exactly - you use B as the "range" since B is the "count" in a Counter object (from collections import Counter)  and then go A*B for as many times as B. so if B=3 then it's A*1, A*2, A*3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I follow you, but maybe you're looking for something like

```
from itertools import product

def lincombs(s):
    terms, ffs = zip(*s)
    factors = product(*(range(f+1) for f in ffs))
    outs = (sum(v*f for v,f in zip(terms, ff)) for ff in factors if any(ff))
    return outs
```

which gives

```
>>> list(lincombs([(500, 2), (250, 1)]))
[250, 500, 750, 1000, 1250]
>>> list(lincombs([(100, 3), (10, 3)]))
[10, 20, 30, 100, 110, 120, 130, 200, 210, 220, 230, 300, 310, 320, 330]
```

Comment: wow, ok that definitely appears to work. Thank you kindly! However, I am completely lost in HOW it works. Can you point me somewhere that I can learn how this code functions? Specifically the * in the product method. and zip method.  Also, this will yield duplicate results, if you start with 500,3 and 250,2 instead of my initial example, but that's easy enough to filter out.  Pretty good at 4 lines + an import! Do you think it's possible to do this with a single list comprehension line?

Comment: @ACVentures: the stararg syntax can be used for any function: `f(*[a, b, c])` is the same as `f(a, b, c)`. You could think of `product` as a cartesian product e.g., `list(product(range(2+1), range(1+1))) == [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]` for the example from the question. btw, I don't see why you've excluded combination where all coefficients are zero from your question. If you want to include it when remove `if any(ff)`.

Comment: I did some research on what zip does, and what the magic asterisk does about the packing and unpacking of tuples. Then I did some research on the product method which also uses the magic asterisk. TIL about magic asterisk and generator expressions... beautiful thing about python is there tends to be something already made that "just does" what you need. For my specific use purpose, there should be no results with zero, or multiplied by zero ever, so they are to be omitted. Finally, I was able to simplify the "outs" return by slapping on a sorted(set(outs)) which yields a nicely ascending list

Answer (score 0):

`v*f` multiplication from [@DSM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22717116/4279) could be avoided:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> terms = [(500, 2), (250, 1)]
>>> map(sum, product(*[xrange(0, v*a+1, v) for v, a in terms]))
[0, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1250]
```

To get a sorted output without duplicates:

```
from itertools import groupby, imap
from operator import itemgetter

it = imap(itemgetter(0), groupby(sorted(it)))
```

though `sorted(set(it))` that you use is ok in this case.